# Computer runs faster on non-focused items?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, focus

I have all of the resources to run just about anything with this computer, and haven't deleted anything important to my computer's well-being.

Whenever I open a webpage or game, I have to change the windows focus for the game or webpage to run properly. I'm not sure why, because when the task manager performance manager is open, it doesnt show any sort of spikes in usage for any of the available pieces (CPU, GPU, memory, etc.). I can run anything just fine, but it runs much quicker (to the point where if I'm only looking at a webpage, clicking on other things will speed the video, game, etc. up)

Here are the computer specs:
Intel I7-6700
MSI Gtx 1070 Aero
32 Gb HyperX Ram 2400Mhz
9 fans with negative pressure towards the back of the case.
Plenty of storage on all drives, but the OS is on a SSD with 400Gb left

What could cause an issue in which the computer slows down things it is focused on for those that it's *not*?

Per @Ramhound's request, I am running Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.228).

Comment: What's your system version?Perform a clean boot and disable security software to check.

Comment: @daidai 10.0.17134 Build 17134

Comment: @Anoplexian - You should provide all relevant information in the body of your question, not in a comment.  10.0.17134 Build 17134 does not make sense, use `winver`, to provide the correct information

Comment: @Ramhound That is the version given to me by windows itself. If you're looking for a specific version for a specific piece of something, then it helps to include how to go about getting that information. I'll provide that version you requested as soon as I'm able.

Comment: Already provided how to get the correct build information, with **winver**, which will display 17134.xxx interested in knowing if you have all cumulative patches installed.  You still should not submit relevant information in a comment

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, I'll get that. My comment was a response that I gave my best interpretation for the original commenter who hadn't provided a way. I didn't even know this was needed information, so I was just pointing it out.

Comment: @Anoplexian I was the original commenter...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83411/discussion-between-anoplexian-and-ramhound).

Comment: 17134 is a completely valid Windows 10 build number. It's not the release number (which is based on the year/month the release is slated for, but it is a valid number provided by Microsoft and is easily associated with a release number by a little Googling.

Comment: I would check for any and all updated drivers and install them. I would also check the Task Manager for how tasks are running while focused and unfocused, and for any software set to run at start/logon.

Comment: @music2myear Nothing changes when task manager is open.

Comment: Task Manager itself should do nothing, but it is a tool to observe WHAT is happening with processes on the computer. In Windows 10 it also has a Startup tab which shows many of the programs starting when Windows starts, and allows you to disable these to see if one of them is the culprit.

Comment: @music2myear That's what I'm saying, nothing changes in task manager, whether for performance, % used on any of the metrics, or anything.